# Getting lowercase string from value types without converting to string first

Tags: c#

I have an `enum`. I need to get the lowercase string representation of this `enum`. Is there a way to get the lowercase without having to create 2 strings first i.e. `enum.ToString().ToLower()`. Is there some `FormatProvider` I can pass into `ToString` to just create a lowercase string and that's it

Comment: Its too much work to type .ToString().ToLower() ?

Comment: @Programnik I'm not sure why you decided to be condescending but no, it's not too much work, however, it is wasteful having to create 2 strings in a high throughput system.

Comment: How about using a `Dictionary<YourEnum, string>`, populated with the lowercase string representations?

Comment: How about using an attribute `[Description("lowercase")]` for each enum item?

Comment: The extra `string` probably has a very minimal impact on performance. But you should not worry too much about that and if you have a performance problem, you should measure anyway.

Comment: @JohanP Here's a good post which discusses this topic: [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99445/228458) I didn't downvote but that's probably part of the reason why your question is getting downvotes. If you want/need to "micro-optimize", you probably should make a case that your concern is indeed a bottleneck (_"Micro-optimization is only important if the numbers say it is"_). Your question, as is, could be interpreted as "I want to get rid of the extra string just because" which some people won't like (and probably rightfully so).

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed for giving me feedback. I wasn't thinking that this case was micro optimisation but rather seeing if there was a way to avoid extra string creation/allocations. I don't consider using `Span` and slicing to avoid excessive allocation a micro optimisation or setting an initial capacity on a `List<T>` but rather a good practice.

Comment: Hi, is there anything you're still unsure about with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to use String's ToLower() method from a non-string value without some sort of ToString() approach.
If it's a syntatical issue, you could make it an extension method:

```
public static string ToLowerString(this YourEnum enumValue) => enumValue.ToString().ToLower();
```

And call it like:

```
YourEnum.SomeEnumValue.ToLowerString();
```

EDIT.

Since the OP said that he/she was trying to avoid overhead, I'm guessing the Dictionary approach suggested by Theodor (`Dictionary<YourEnum, string>`) is a much better solution.

Comment: Which basically does the same thing (maybe plus the extension method overhead). The OP mentioned that he/she is concerned about creating two strings, not about having to type `.ToString().ToLower()` every time.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yeah, I was going for the syntactic matter. Didn't noticed that comment. Additional information should be added as an edit in the question rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a lookup dictionary, initialize it once at startup (or the first time it's needed), and use this to obtain the lowercase values:

```
public static Dictionary<TEnum, string> BuildEnumToStringMapping<TEnum>()
    where TEnum: struct
{
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("TEnum is not an enum.");
        }

        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            .OfType<TEnum>()
            .ToDictionary(e => e, e => e.ToString().ToLower());
}
```

Usage:

```
var lookup = BuildEnumToStringMapping<MyEnum>();
Console.WriteLine(lookup[MyEnum.Value]);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/TOI91671)

Answer (score 0):

There are no many ways of achieving this as you do not want two strings (It will void possibility to use `ToString().ToLower()`).

I would suggest to use `DescriptionAttribute` from the namespace `System.ComponentModel`.

Add `DescriptionAttribute` to each member of the enumeration.

```
public enum Items
{
    [Description("item1")]
    Item1 = 1,

    [Description("item2")]
    Item2 = 2,
}
```

Then use `Reflection` to get friendly lowercase name when required.

```
public static string GetDescription(Enum en)
{
    Type type = en.GetType();

    MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
    }

    return en.ToString();
}
```

**Reference: check [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/enumhelper-getting-a-friendly-description-from-an-enum) for more details.**

Comment: @kame No. It won't. It will return "Item1" not lowecase "item1".